# getting object out from nsarray

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsarray, xcode4.3

I'm new to objective c. There are a couple of object which i want to take out from this array results with is from JSON and i need help. How do i get objects out from this array? how can i get the features then the attributes and route name etc.

```
NSArray *directions=[jsonResult objectForKey:@"directions"];

    int i;
    NSArray *dict;
    int count = [directions count];
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {            
        NSLog (@"directions = %@", [directions objectAtIndex: i]);          
    }
```

> The object that i want to get from

```
directions = {
features =     (
            {
        attributes =             {
            ETA = 1341190800000;
            length = 0;
            maneuverType = esriDMTDepart;
            text = "Start at 18304.680000,36152.730000";
            time = 0;
        };
        compressedGeometry = "+1+hrt+139j+0+0";
    },
            {
        attributes =             {
            ETA = 1341190800000;
            length = "1.43124650292492";
            maneuverType = esriDMTStraight;
            text = "Go southeast on PAN ISLAND EXPRESSWAY";
            time = "1.22675858855561";
        };
        compressedGeometry = "+1+hrt+139j+i9-a6+kp-bl";
    }
routeId = 1;
routeName = "18304.680000,36152.730000 - 29663.160389,40202.513760";
summary =     {
    envelope =         {
        spatialReference =             {
            wkid = 3414;
        };
        xmax = "29663.160018156";
        xmin = "18301.4360762186";
        ymax = "40229.9300290999";
        ymin = "35091.9900291003";
    };
    totalDriveTime = "24.8214824061658";
    totalLength = "17.2089251018779";
    totalTime = "24.8";
};
```

how can i do it?

Comment: What is the type of `jsonResult`?

Comment: the jsonresults that i got is the direction={...} mention abv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[directions objectAtIndex: i]` returns `NSDictionary`, if you want to get objects from it, do the following

```
NSDictionary *dic = [directions objectAtIndex: i];
[dic valueForKey:@"routeName"] //route name
[dic valueForKey:@"routeId"] //routeId
[dic valueForKey:@"features"] //returns an nsdictionery too
[[dic valueForKey:@"features"] valueForKey:@"text"] //returns an nsdictionery too
```

And so on

Comment: hmm.. do i have to put the object as NSDictionary?

Comment: the directions array already contains a dictionary, you will just need to get the values out of it

Comment: thx. for the features is it an array? cos i have to get the attributes

Comment: featues is an nsdictionary too, you can get each value inside it using valueForKey too

Comment: [dic valueForKey:@"attributes"]; and it got me a null how should i get it?

Comment: use this instead [[dic valueForKey:@"features"] valueForKey:@"attributes"];

Answer (score 1):

each object inside directions is an `NSDictionary`, and each object inside them is also a dictionary. So you will need something like this:

```
NSDictionary *directions=[jsonResult objectForKey:@"directions"];
NSDictionary *features = [directions objectForKey:@"features"];
```

...and so on, until you get all the values.

Comment: can't work it got this error -[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xde3c210

Comment: Please post code on how you get jsonResult. It seems you're trying to access an NSArray as a dictionary.

Comment: responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:format];

        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        
        
        
        NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

        NSDictionary *jsonResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:result options:kNilOptions error:&error];